# Unexpected token ILLEGAL - ckeditor value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ckeditor, syntax-error

I am using ckeditor in my project which converts the user's input to html as follows:

```
<p>summary:</p>

<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
</ul>
```

When fetching this data in jquery as follow:

```
var title = "{{$p->title}}";
var start = "{{$p->start_date}}";
var end = "{{$p->end_date}}";
var summary = '{{$p->summary}}';
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

at the summary var.By inspecting the element, it's as follow:

```
var summary = '<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>tes2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
</ul>
';
```

I know it may sound a clumsy mistake but I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Read: [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript string literals cannot include unescaped literal new line characters.

If you want to convert a PHP variables to a JavaScript string, then use `json_encode`, don't echo it out blindly.

```
$js_safe = array(
    title => json_encode($p->title),
    # etc
);
```

Then:

```
var title = {{$js_safe->title}};
```

Note that `json_encode` will add quotes for you.